# Vector calculus - Evaluate this line integral

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

Question:
[image]

> Suppose $F(x,y)=2sin(x/2)sin(y/2)i - 2cos(x/2)cos(y/2)j$. 
>   C is the curve from $P$ to $Q$, where $P(-3\pi/2,3\pi/2),Q(-3\pi/2,-3\pi/2),R(3\pi/2,3\pi/2),S(3\pi/2,-3\pi/2)$.The curves $PR$ and $SQ$ are trigonometric function of period 2\pi and amplitude 1.

[image]

My attempt:

> integrate C $Fdr$ = integrate C $F(x(t),y(t))r'(t)dt$, so I split the question into 3 parts:
>    1. integrate t from -3pi/2 to 3pi/2   $<2sin(t/2)sin(cos(t)/2), -2cos(t/2)cos(cos(t)/2)>⋅<1,-sin(t)>dt$
>    2. integrate t from 0 to 1
>   $<2sin(3pi/4)sin((3pi/2-3pi*t)/2), -2cos(3pi/4)cos((3pi/2-3pi*t)/2)>⋅<0,-3pi/2>dt$
>    3. integrate t from 3pi/2 to -3pi/2
>   $<2sin(t/2)sin(sin(t)/2), -2cos(t/2)cos(sin(t)/2)>⋅<1, cos(t)>dt$

Are my steps correct? But they are even too complicated that I cannot use calculator to solve them.

Comment: Some MathJax hints: `\cos`, `\sin`, `\pi`, `\frac t2`.

Comment: Also, `\times` or `\cdot`, although I would recommend dropping the multiplication symbol altogether most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $F(x,y)=A(x,y)\vec{i}+B(x,y)\vec{j}$, if $\displaystyle \frac{dA}{dy}=\frac{dB}{dx}$, then the vector field is conservative and has an "antiderivative".

Consider the potential function $F^*(x,y)=-4\cos(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{y}{2})$.

The derivative (or vector field) corresponding to $F^*$ is F, as we can see through differentiation.

Now, we can just take $F^*(Q)-F^*(P)$.

Comment: I found the potential function is $-4\sin(y/2)\cos(x/2)+y+K$, where K is a constant, but how can I find K?

Comment: You don’t need to! And by the way, you can’t. It’s an arbitrary constant.